# Rails 3 retain value of Dropdown box which is populated by ajax after validation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Have three dropdown box for country,state and city.

```
.entry.float
 %label{:for => "hospital-country"} Country
 = select_tag :country_id, options_for_select(["Select option"] + @countries.collect{ |c| [c.name, c.id] },@hospital.country_id),{:name =>"hospital[country_id]",:class => "select r5",:id => "hospital-country",:onchange=>"country_change()"}

.entry.float
 %label{:for => "hospital-state"} State
 = select_tag :state, options_for_select(["Select option"]),{:name =>"hospital[state]",:id => 'hospital-state',:class => "select r5",:disabled => true,:onchange=>"state_change()"}

.entry.float
 %label{:for => "hospital-city"} City
 = select_tag :city, options_for_select(["Select option"]),{:name =>"hospital[city]",:id => 'hospital-city',:class => "select r5",:disabled => true}
```

In which country is populated by `

> @countries = WorldCountry.all

`
and state and cities are populated by ajax call of country and state dropdown box respectively using jquery

```
function country_change() {
    $('#hospital-state').find('option[value!="Select option"]').remove();
    $('#hospital-state').next().text("Select option");
    $('#hospital-state').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#hospital-city').find('option[value!="Select option"]').remove();
    $('#hospital-city').next().text("Select option");
    $('#hospital-city').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    if ($('#hospital-country').val() != "" && $('#hospital-country').val() != "Select option") {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'post',
            url : '/hospitals/country_change',
            data : {
                country_id : $('#hospital-country').val()
            },
            dataType : "json",
            success : function(data) {
                var select = $('#hospital-state');
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    select.removeAttr('disabled');
                    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                        $("<option/>").val(value[1]).text(value[0]).appendTo(select);
                    });
                } 
            },
            failure : function() {
            }
        })
    } 
};
```

All this are working. But when validation fails i can only retain the value of country.
How to retain the value of State and Cities which works only in ajax.

Comment: you don't pass the selected value to the `options_for_select` for city and state. so there won't be anything selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the view as

```
.entry.float
 %label{:for => "hospital-state"} State
 -if !@states.blank?
   = select_tag :state, options_for_select(["Select option"] + @states.collect{ |s| [s.name, s.id] },@selected_state),{:name =>"hospital[state]",:class => "select r5",:id => "hospital-state",:onchange=>"state_change()"}
 - else
   = select_tag :state, options_for_select(["Select option"]),{:name =>"hospital[state]",:id => 'hospital-state',:class => "select r5",:onchange=>"state_change()"}
.entry.float
 %label{:for => "hospital-city"} City
 - if !@cities.blank?
 = select_tag :city, options_for_select(["Select option"] + @cities.collect{ |c| [c.name, c.id] },@selected_city),{:name =>"hospital[city]",:class => "select r5",:id => "hospital-state"}
 -else
 = select_tag :city, options_for_select(["Select option"]),{:name =>"hospital[city]",:id => 'hospital-city',:class => "select r5",:disabled => true}
```

And in the controler
if validation fails

```
@states =WorldRegion.where("world_country_id=?",params[:hospital][:country_id])
@selected_state = WorldRegion.find_by_id(params[:hospital][:state]).id rescue nil 
@cities = WorldCity.where("world_country_id=? and world_region_id=?",params[:hospital][:country_id],params[:hospital][:state])
@selected_city = WorldCity.find_by_id(params[:hospital][:city]).id rescue nil     
render action: "new"
```

It works fine. 
Thanks
hari